# pipe ggplot2 w/ dynamic title

Tags: r, ggplot2, pipe

Can I get to the data and make a title with a pipe in a ggplot?

Say I have data like this,

```
x <- c(5,17,31,9,17,10,30,28,16,29,14,34)
y <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
day <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)

df2 <- reshape2::melt(df1, id.vars='day') %>% data.frame(x, y, day, company = 'inc. company name ')

df2 %>% ggplot(aes(x=day, y=value, fill=variable), xlab="Age Group") + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = 0.5)
```

[image: wher I'm at]

However I would like to do something like this

```
df2 %>% ggplot(aes(x=day, y=value, fill=variable), xlab="Age Group") + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = 0.5) +
  + labs(title = paste0(.$company, "numbers")) # NOT WOKRING CODE
```

To get to this,
[image: wher eI would like to go]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fence in the entire ggplot2 bit in a single expression, which allows you to use the `.` pronoun throughout ggplot2 calls. I don't see why you'd want to do this except for saving 2 keystrokes, but you could.

```r
library(tidyverse)

x <- c(5,17,31,9,17,10,30,28,16,29,14,34)
y <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
day <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)

df1 <- data.frame(x = x, y = y, day = day)

df2 <- reshape2::melt(df1, id.vars='day') %>% data.frame(x, y, day, company = 'inc. company name ')

df2 %>% {
  ggplot(., aes(x=day, y=value, fill=variable), xlab="Age Group") + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = 0.5) +
    labs(title = paste0(.$company, "numbers"))
}
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-02-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
 df2 %>% ggplot(aes(x=day, y=value, fill=variable), xlab="Age Group") + 
   geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = 0.5) +
    labs(title = paste0(first(df2$company), "numbers"))
```

-output

[image]

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question! I am however looking for a solution that's utilizing the piping, so that I do not have to restate `df2`. With the above solution I would have writhe a classical `df2$...`, with is what I am looking to get around with the `pipe`.