# Use column-values from dataframe passed to ggplot to set the breaks

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I have this dataframe (for this example with only one column).

```
> head(df)
  n
1 4
2 3
3 2
4 3
5 3
6 1
```

This reproduces the dataframe:

```
structure(list(n = c(4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L)), row.names = c(NA, -32L), class = "data.frame")
```

Now when I do the following ggplot. The breaks are not set for every integer value.

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_bar(
    mapping = aes(x = n)
  )
```

So I want to use the maximum value from the column `n` and create breaks for each integer in between. I could certainly extract the max-value outside of the ggplot function call. But I would like to do it inside. However, I did not figure out a way to do it. I tried using the `.`-notation and the curly-braces. But I just don't manage to make it work...

This is one of my  tries:

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_bar(
    mapping = aes(x = n)
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:max(.$n))
```

Answer (score 2):

Set breaks and labels.

```
  ggplot(df) +
    geom_bar(
      mapping = aes(x = n)
    ) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:max(df$n), labels = 1:max(df$n))
```

Comment: thank a lot! What if I pipe the dataframe into the `ggplot`-call and it doesn't have variable name as in this case?

Comment: You can fence the entire ggplot2 expression in curly brackets to use the `.` pronoun (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66106960/11374827). You can also just assign to a variable at the end of a pipe and use that as ggplot2 input.